# Convert NPOT PVR texture to POT within iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, pvrtc

I would like to manually load NPOT PVR textures on iOS (I don't mean loading the texture in OpenGL memory, I mean loading it in a custom data structure that allows accessing the image data in order enlarge the canvas and save it again as a new PVR).

I am asking this because we are implementing an OpenGL iOS application with lots of background textures (480 x 320 on non retina displays). We intend to store this textures as NPOT PVR files, so we have memory gains on 3GS+ iPhones.

3G- iPhone cannot load NPOT PVR textures in non OpenGL memory. My intentions are to implement a preprocessing step for 3G- devices that converts all NPOT PVRs textures to POT PVRs and stores them on the app's Cache folder.

Is it possible to load and process a PVR in this way? For example, a TexturePacker generated PVR.

Comment: For the shake of correctness, I just realized that we don't want to resize the canvas of PVRTC textures. Instead we want to resize the canvas of PVR files (the container) which encapsulate a regular RGB444A format, which will be waaaay easier. Anyway, thanks for the answers, as they helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is.

1. Decompress the file format.
2. Scale raw image data
3. Compress new scaled data and save

For step one, see https://github.com/Volcore/quickpvr or PowerVR's SDK.

For step three there is no publicly available documentation or implementation of PVRTC compression. So you have several options. Use the combination of class-dump and otx to decompile Apple
s texturetool (not advisable), or (and probably easier) write your own encoder based on whatever specification of the file format you can conjure from step 1.

However, given your situation I would just do this all as a preprocessed step and include two versions of your textures along with your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We would prefer not to include the two versions along the app, because there are a *ton* of them, and that would increase the IPA size considerably. Also, isn't there any way of using PowerVR's SDK to generate the file of step 3 from iOS? How other tools (like TexturePacker) are able to write PVR compressed files?

Comment: And by the way, for the shake of correctness, step 2 would be "Add transparent pixels to raw image data".

Comment: You know what, I never noticed this before, but this may be of use to you: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtexlib.asp. I haven't it out yet, but it be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the texture to automatically repeat/wrap and are just going to use your 480 x 320 texels as a subset of, say, a 512x512 texture and never access parts where X > 480 and y > 320, then you could rearrange the data.

One suggestion would be to pad your source images up to  512x512 (using some constant colour), compress them, and then just store the relevant parts of the texture. When you come to load the texture in the application, just re-pad out with the missing compressed data. (Just realised that's not the clearest of descriptions :-| ).

Note that you'd need to take into account the storage order (which is probably described in the link that bronxbomber92 gave) but it just occurred to me that there might be a simpler approach. 
The compressed data is arranged/interleaved in 64-bit chunks. If you have padded your source image with a constant colour, after compression (at least with the IMG PVRTextool compressor) there should then be a reasonable percentage (~38%) of 64-bit chunks which are the same. You could use, say, a set of flags to mark which 64-bit words use this 'same' constant to avoid storing that data.